# Facebook Graph API v2 Dashboard: is it possible to see the breakdown of "% of API Calls in v2.x"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Currently, our "% of API Calls in v2.x" is at 98% and we'd like to see Facebook's side of the breakdown by call. Is this possible?